A more efficient way of extracting a list of groups of indices from an array within a given range in Python
A scenario I have is I have three arrays:

An array of an upper bound
An array of a lower bound
A target array

What I want to get is a list of arrays which contain the indices of the target array which are within the boundary arrays for each index e.g.:
ub_arr = [4,5,6]

lb_arr = [1,2,3]

target_arr = [12, 3, 5, 10, 6, 1, 3, 4]

The outcome would be:
[[1, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 6, 7], [1, 2, 4, 6, 7]]

At the moment the code I am using looks something like:
matching_indices = []
for idx in range(len(ub_arr)):
    indices = np.array(np.where((target_arr >= lb_arr[idx]) & (target_arr <= ub_arr)))
    matching_indices.append(indices)


IF we then have to check across two different target arrays, each with their upper bounds, I then reduce each index in the target matching_indices list to get the intersection of the indices.
I was wondering whether there was a more efficient way of doing this?
[EDIT]
Potential test arrays could be generated:
ub_arr = np.random.uniform(0,10,10_000)
lb_arr = np.random.uniform(0,10,10_000)
target_arr = np.random.uniform(0,10,20_000)


Your example is not making any sense. where does 7 came from?

Should the middle output be [1,2,6,7]?

@inspectorG4dget correct my bad

@Moshen_Fatemi the 7 is the final index in the target array

if you do not mind having the indices in an unsorted order, consider using shortcircuited method on a sorted array to determine the indices. Use the merge sort radix

I suggest to use binary search (e.g. bisect built-in module):
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

ub_arr = [4, 5, 6]
lb_arr = [1, 2, 3]
target_arr = [12, 3, 5, 10, 6, 1, 3, 4]

idxs, vals = zip(*sorted(enumerate(target_arr), key=lambda k: k[1]))

out = []
for l, u in zip(lb_arr, ub_arr):
    a, b = bisect_left(vals, l), bisect_right(vals, u)
    out.append(idxs[a:b])

print(out)

Prints:
[(5, 1, 6, 7), (1, 6, 7, 2), (1, 6, 7, 2, 4)]


OR: Use numpy:
idxs = np.argsort(target_arr)
vals = target_arr[idxs]

a = np.searchsorted(vals, lb_arr, side="left")
b = np.searchsorted(vals, ub_arr, side="right")

out = []
for i, j in zip(a, b):
    out.append(idxs[i:j])

print(out)


Benchmark:
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np


def get_arrays():
    lb_arr = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 10_000)
    ub_arr = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 10_000)
    target_arr = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 20_000)
    return lb_arr, ub_arr, target_arr


def get_indices(lb_arr, ub_arr, target_arr):
    idxs, vals = zip(*sorted(enumerate(target_arr), key=lambda k: k[1]))

    out = []
    for l, u in zip(lb_arr, ub_arr):
        a, b = bisect_left(vals, l), bisect_right(vals, u)
        out.append(idxs[a:b])

    return out


def get_indices_numpy(lb_arr, ub_arr, target_arr):
    idxs = np.argsort(target_arr)
    vals = target_arr[idxs]

    a = np.searchsorted(vals, lb_arr, side="left")
    b = np.searchsorted(vals, ub_arr, side="right")

    out = []
    for i, j in zip(a, b):
        out.append(idxs[i:j])
    return out


def get_indices_original(lb_arr, ub_arr, target_arr):
    matching_indices = []
    for idx in range(len(ub_arr)):
        indices = np.array(
            np.where((target_arr >= lb_arr[idx]) & (target_arr <= ub_arr[idx]))
        )
        matching_indices.append(indices)
    return matching_indices


t_python = timeit(
    "get_indices(l, u, t)", setup="l,u,t=get_arrays()", globals=globals(), number=1
)
t_numpy = timeit(
    "get_indices_numpy(l, u, t)",
    setup="l,u,t=get_arrays()",
    globals=globals(),
    number=1,
)
t_original = timeit(
    "get_indices_original(l, u, t)",
    setup="l,u,t=get_arrays()",
    globals=globals(),
    number=1,
)

print(f"{t_python=}")
print(f"{t_numpy=}")
print(f"{t_original=}")

This prints on my computer (AMD 5700x/Python 3.11):
t_python=0.1390752261504531
t_numpy=0.005280003882944584
t_original=0.2402120700571686


Great, thank you! I can see similar benchmarks on my own test set with both solutions leading to speed increases. I will likely adapt the numpy solution for consistency and speed.

Fiddle with the inequalities, but this should do the trick
In [79]: lowerbound = [1,2,3]

In [80]: upperbound = [4,5,6]

In [81]: target = [12, 3, 5, 10, 6, 1, 3, 4]

In [82]: answer = []

In [83]: answer = [[] for _ in lowerbound]

In [84]: answer
Out[84]: [[], [], []]

In [85]: for t in target:
    ...:     for i,(lb,ub) in enumerate(zip(lowerbound, upperbound)):
    ...:         if lb <= t <= ub:
    ...:             answer[i].append(t)
    ...:

In [86]: answer  # oops! I added the actual elements rather than their indices
Out[86]: [[3, 1, 3, 4], [3, 5, 3, 4], [3, 5, 6, 3, 4]]

In [87]: answer = [[] for _ in lowerbound]

In [88]: for t,num in enumerate(target):
    ...:     for i,(lb,ub) in enumerate(zip(lowerbound, upperbound)):
    ...:         if lb <= num <= ub:
    ...:             answer[i].append(t)
    ...:
    ...:

In [89]: answer
Out[89]: [[1, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 6, 7], [1, 2, 4, 6, 7]]


Unfortunately much slower than the original solution

For a pure numpy approach, you could use broadcasting, np.nonzero and array_split:
# broadcast comparison with the lower/upper bounds
# get the indices of True
idx, col = np.nonzero((target_arr >= lb_arr[:, None])
                    & (target_arr <= ub_arr[:, None]))
# group the col indices per row (= per initial pair of lower/upper bounds)
out = np.array_split(col, np.nonzero(np.diff(idx))[0]+1)

Output:
[np.array([1, 5, 6, 7]), np.array([1, 2, 6, 7]), np.array([1, 2, 4, 6, 7])]

Intermediates:
# idx
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
# col
array([1, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 6, 7, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7])


Currently with boundaries of size 10_000 and target of size 20_000 this is about twice as slow as the current solution in the original question and generates very large idx and col arrays

@Philip09 you haven't provided code to set up a test array, please edit your question.

True, apologies! Have added code to generate test arrays
